# Replace characters in foreach variable

Tags: scala, gatling

Here is the code:

```
    def readEntityMultipleTimes(entityName: String, pathPrefix: String = "") = {
      val plural = entityName + "s"
      exec(http(s"Geting all $plural")
        .get(pathPrefix + plural)
        .check(status is 200)
        .check(jsonPath("$[*].id").findAll.saveAs("entityIds"))
      ).exec(s => {
          if (logLevel >= 2) println("\nids:\n" + s("entityIds"))
          s
      })
      .pause(interval millis)
      .foreach("${entityIds}", "entityId") {
        repeat(readEntityNumber) {
          exec(http(s"Getting one $entityName")
            .get(pathPrefix + plural + "/${entityId}") 
            .check(status is 200)
          )
        }
      }
    }
```

The issue is that `entityId` may contain a space and it fails the HTTP GET request. I need the spaces to be replaced with `%20`.

I tried the gatling EL `${entityId.replaceAll(\" \", \"%20\")}"`
or `${java.net.URLEncoder.encode(entityId)}`

I guess the suggested way is to get the `entityId` from the session and do the stuff in Scala, but this variable is dynamically created for each loop iteration, so I am not sure where to put the "session lambda" (session => ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gatling EL syntax is limited and you can't place any Scala code in there.

You indeed have to pass a function.

```
.get(session => pathPrefix + plural + URLEncoder.encode(session("entityId").as[String])))
```